# Python and SPSS giving different output for Logistic Regression

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, spss

Code:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
l = LogisticRegression()
b = l.fit(XT,Y)
    print "coeff ",b.coef_
    print "intercept ",b.intercept_
```

Here's the dataset

```
XT =
[[23]
 [24]
 [26]
 [21]
 [29]
 [31]
 [27]
 [24]
 [22]
 [23]]
Y = [1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0]
```

Result:

```
coeff  [[ 0.00850441]]
intercept  [-0.15184511
```

Now I added the same data in spss.Analyse->Regression->Binary Logistic Regression. I set the corresponding Y -> dependent and XT -> Covariates. The results weren't even close. Am I missing something in python or SPSS?
[image: Result of binary logistic regression on SPSS]Python-Sklearn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SPSS Logistic regression does not include parameter regularisation in it's cost function, it just does 'raw' logistic regression.  In regularisation, the cost function includes a regularisation expression to prevent overfitting.  You specify the inverse of this with the C value.  If you set C to a very high value, it will closely mimic SPSS, so there is no magic number - just set it as high as you can, and there will be no regularisation.

Answer (score 3):

Solved it myself. I tried changing the C-value in `LinearRegression(C=100)`. That did the trick. `C=1000` got the result closest to `SPSS` and `textbook` result.

Hope this helps anyone who face any problem with `LogisticRegression` in `python`.

Comment: So I got another question. Why is the default C value not giving the result as in SPSS or textbook? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

With `sklearn` you can also "turn off" the regularization by setting the penalty to `None`. Then, no regularization will be applied. This will provide similar results for the logistic regression in `sklearn` compared to SPSS.

An example of a logistic regression from `sklearn` with 1000 iterations and no penalty is:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
lr = LogisticRegression(max_iter=1000, penalty='none')
```

Comment: Please go through [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). It is expected that steps or minimal working code is provided.